# Multiple matrices side-by-side in org-mode (export to LaTeX and HTML)

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex, html, math

How do I display multiple matrices side-by-side in an org-mode document so that they are exported nicely to LaTeX and HTML documents? Currently, I'm using the following but the result is not what I expect:

```
      #+ATTR_LATEX: :mode math :environment bmatrix :math-prefix A =  :math-suffix , c \neq 0,
      |c | 0 |
      |0 | 1 |
      #+ATTR_LATEX: :mode math :environment bmatrix :math-prefix , B = :math-suffix , d \geq 0.
      |1 | 0 |
      |0 | d |
```

I would like this to be exported as `A = [] , c \neq 0, B = [] , d \geq 0.` without line breaks in between (where `[]` contains matrix elements).

Comment: That's how the PDF produced by the LaTeX exporter looks in my case (except for an extra comma). HTML is a different kettle of fish though.

Comment: @NickD Yes it works for PDF but in HTML, I get four HTML tables arranged vertically.  Nothing like matrices. The ```:math-suffix``` and prefix don't seem to work too.

Comment: Well, `#+ATTR_LATEX` attributes only apply for the LaTeX exporter. You could try adding `#+ATTR_HTML` attributes as well, but I suspect it wouldn't work: you'd probably have to supplement the HTML exporter's efforts with some tag to group all of the elements and then provide some CSS to style that tag. If you can modify the (currently imperfect) exported HTML file somehow to do what you expect, then it might be possible to suggest how to reverse-engineer the result into the Org mode file.